# Valid proof technique for proving compactness of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

My goal is to prove that if given that the product space $X \times Y$ of two topological spaces is compact, then $X$ and $Y$ are compact. My idea for proof technique is as follows.

1. Prove that the projection mappings $\operatorname{\pi}: X \times Y \to X$ and $\operatorname{\pi}: X \times Y \to Y$ are continuous.
2. Prove that the image of the projection mapping is the whole space $X$ and $Y$.
3. Suppose that either space $X$ or $Y$ is not compact. Use Theorem 26.5 from Munkres ("the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact") to show that this results in a contradiction.

I am fairly confident in step one and step three is a gimme. My questioning lies in step 2. I am wondering:

1. Is step 2 even true
2. If it is true, is this something that is generally accepted in topology or if it needs proving.

I also am looking for feedback to see if as a whole this proof would be sound and valid. If anyone has alternate proof technique ideas, I would gladly be open to listening.

Comment: Step 2 is both true and trivial, and you don’t need to make this a proof by contradiction: once you have the first two steps, just apply Theorem 26.5 to conclude directly that $X$ and $Y$ are compact.

Comment: Careful! Step 2 fails if one of $X$ or $Y$ is empty! And in fact the original statement isn't true in this case. (But as soon as $X$ or $Y$ are both non-empty it's very straightforward.)

Comment: And quite a few people by definition require spaces to be non-empty, as I usually do. If you’re working from a particular book, you should try to see whether it allows empty spaces; if it does, or if you can’t tell, or if you’re not working from any source, then you should definitely note that exception.

Comment: I am indeed working with non-empty spaces. Thank you all for the tips! was pretty sure this would work, but I like to check with the community to be sure. I also want to make sure step 1 is not trivial? If it is, this proof is as short as a few statements

Comment: Never mind, while I did not treat it as trivial, I simply stated that the preimage of any open subset of $X$ or $Y$ will also (obviously) be open in $XxY$ and completed the proof shortly thereafter

Comment: I don't know the book of Munkres. I'm just wondering whether he requires compact spaces to be Hausdorff? In this case, of course, only Hausdorff images of compact spaces are compact. And in your proof you still need to show that X and Y are Hausdorff, which can easily be done by an embedding of X and Y, respectively, into $X \times Y$, provided that X, Y are non-empty. BTW, this also yields an alternative proof of compactness of X and Y.

Comment: @Ulli Munkres does not require Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

If exactly one of the spaces $X , Y$ is empty, then the projection to the other space is not onto because $X \times Y = \emptyset$.

If $X, Y = \emptyset$ or $X, Y \ne \emptyset$, then 2. is true by definition of the product.